# ROS Answers SE migration: ros2 latching

Tags: python, ros2, ros-bouncy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I can't get message latching (transient local durability) to work in Bouncy. Here's my Python test case:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import rclpy
from rclpy.node import Node
from rclpy.qos import QoSProfile, QoSDurabilityPolicy
from std_msgs.msg import String


class Latching(Node):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('latching')
        latching_qos = QoSProfile(depth=1,
            durability=QoSDurabilityPolicy.RMW_QOS_POLICY_DURABILITY_TRANSIENT_LOCAL)
        pub = self.create_publisher(String, 'foo', qos_profile=latching_qos)
        msg = String(data='test')
        pub.publish(msg)


def main(args=None):
    rclpy.init(args=args)
    node = Latching()

    try:
        rclpy.spin(node)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        node.get_logger().info("Ctrl-C detected, shutting down")
    finally:
        node.destroy_node()
        rclpy.shutdown()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

When I run `ros2 topic echo /foo std_msgs/String` first, then run my node, I see message `test` published on topic `/foo` as expected.

However, when I run my node before running `ros2 topic echo /foo std_msgs/String`, nothing shows up. Shouldn't I see the latched message?

I wonder if this might be related to https://answers.ros.org/question/304645/ros2-robot-state-publisher-publishes-empty-robot_description/

I'm using FastRTPS.

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/305795/ros2-latching/) by [clyde](https://answers.ros.org/users/28405/clyde/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1247 on 2018-10-14

Post score: 8

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [clyde](https://answers.ros.org/users/28405/clyde/) on 2018-10-15**:
I just tested this w/ a Python listener with the same QoS. Still no luck: if the publisher runs first, then the subscriber gets the message. If the publisher runs second, the subscriber never gets the message.

**Comment by [ahlyder](https://answers.ros.org/users/36752/ahlyder/) on 2019-06-04**:
Did you ever get this to work? And if so, how?

**Comment by [clyde](https://answers.ros.org/users/28405/clyde/) on 2019-06-06**:
I did not. Workarounds: (1) for rviz, read the URDF from a file, not from a message. (2) publish static messages periodically, perhaps once every 5s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I haven't tried Bouncy, but as of today's Dashing this slightly modified code taken from the question works for me:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import rclpy
from rclpy.node import Node
from rclpy.qos import QoSProfile, QoSDurabilityPolicy
from std_msgs.msg import String


class Latching(Node):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('latching_sub')
        latching_qos = QoSProfile(depth=1,
            durability=QoSDurabilityPolicy.RMW_QOS_POLICY_DURABILITY_TRANSIENT_LOCAL)
        sub = self.create_subscription(String, 'foo', self.callback, qos_profile=latching_qos)

    def callback(self, str_msg):
        self.get_logger().info('Got message: ' + str(str_msg))


def main(args=None):
    rclpy.init(args=args)
    node = Latching()

    try:
        rclpy.spin(node)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        node.get_logger().info("Ctrl-C detected, shutting down")
    finally:
        node.destroy_node()
        rclpy.shutdown()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

No matter the order I run the two nodes (publisher first and subscriber second or vice-versa), I always see the callback in the subscriber called. I've tested it using FastRTPS as well.

Hope it helps!

PS: for reference, this issue has a good summary of the differences between ROS1 latching and transient local settings: https://github.com/ros2/ros2/issues/464.

---

Originally posted by [jubeira](https://answers.ros.org/users/29146/jubeira/) with karma: 1054 on 2019-07-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [clyde](https://answers.ros.org/users/28405/clyde/) on 2019-07-03**:
This works! The upshot is that `ros2 topic echo` won't match transient local topics. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use `ros2 topic echo`, you just need to set correct QoS profile and durability:

```
ros2 topic echo --qos-profile services_default --qos-durability transient_local foo
```

---

BTW, maybe it is better to use `DurabilityPolicy.TRANSIENT_LOCAL` instead of `QoSDurabilityPolicy.RMW_QOS_POLICY_DURABILITY_TRANSIENT_LOCAL` as it is done in `static_transform_broadcaster`:
https://github.com/ros2/geometry2/blob/6788c1b78fe35e1a459a9d8f184afeb79792bd71/tf2_ros/src/tf2_ros/static_transform_broadcaster.py#L55

---

Originally posted by [lukicdarkoo](https://answers.ros.org/users/44970/lukicdarkoo/) with karma: 486 on 2020-04-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [clyde](https://answers.ros.org/users/28405/clyde/) on 2020-05-04**:
Ah, very cool. IIUC this was added in Eloquent. https://github.com/ros2/ros2cli/pull/283

Good point on `DurabilityPolicy.TRANSIENT_LOCAL`.